# What is the best free, Ajax.NET (System.Web.Extensions 3.5) compatible Rich Text Box control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, richtext, ajax.net

I'm looking for a good ASP.NET RichTextBox component that integrates fairly easily with .NET Framework 3.5 Ajax, specifically one that can easily provide its values from inside an UpdatePanel.

I got burned by RicherComponents RichTextBox which still does not reference the Framework 3.5.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at FCKEditor for a free solution.  I'm unsure if it's usable inside an update panel, but it's free and opensource.

http://www.fckeditor.net/

Comment: The latest version of the FCKEditor works perfectly in an update panel.  I just switched from the crappy RicherComponents RTB which did not work (same as the OP's situation).

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider going with an HTML editor instead of a Rich Text format editor, I recommend the Telerik web editor.  It is very flexible and integrates quite solidly with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Googled based on craigmoliver's answer and found this:
http://www.webcitation.org/5bFQaq7Wp

Basically, it's a solution to allow FCKEditor to work in an update panel, which I will try and post if it work.

Comment: Oh, also from the FCKSite: "July 26, 2008 - FCKeditor.Net 2.6.3 released : This new version of our ASP.Net integration fixes incompatibility issues with the Microsoft ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel. Other minor fixes are also included."